# gcc takes much memory to compile c++ file with very large object on stack

Tags: c++, gcc, memory, stack-overflow

I have a c++ file which uses a `std::bitset<size>`. When compiling using gcc on windows subsystem linux, if `size = 1000000000` (1Gbit) cause about 1.6GB compile-time memory using, `size = 10000000000` (10Gbit) cause about ~6GB memory and ~15GB virtual memory (my PC has 8GB memory in total). The memory is allocated gradually and the compilation finishes immediately after the maximum.
The program runs into `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` as soon as launching if `size` is large. The turning point is between 10M and 100M.

On MSVC, the program compiles and runs good if `size` is small. For larger `size` an exception is thrown: "Stack overflow". If `size` is really large it gives error "total size of array must not exceed 0x7fffffff bytes" in file `bitset`

The problem is irrelevant to  optimization level. No matter -O0, -O1,
 -O2 or O3, it is the same.

this is the output of `gcc -v`:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)
```

This is my test code, very simple

```
#include <bitset>

int main(){
    const size_t size = ...;
    std::bitset<size> bs;
    return 0;
}
```

If gcc-8 is used instead of gcc-7 there is no such issue, the compilation finishes quick, and the program runs into segmentation fault if `size` is large,as it should be.
If I use `vector<bool>` or create the bitset using `new`,it runs good.

So there is no problem to solve but my question is:

Why gcc-7 takes so much memory (and time) to compile the file?

Comment: Could you provide the arguments/flags you're providing to gcc for compilation?

Comment: no argument,-O0,-O1,-O2,O3, all the same

Comment: gcc crash reproduces similarly [on wandbox with gcc-7.3](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YgiTSA9vMegGse9r) but compiles and fails with a seg fault at runtime (as expected) [with gcc-8.1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jujVxhBD8i6tkbN5). clang doesn't seem to have this issue either.

Comment: You're trying to create an object on the stack that takes up more memory that your stack's maximum size. So, yeah, crash...

Comment: @Shawn I understand this. But why gcc uses so much memory

Comment: @RyanHaining yes, the compilation finishes immediately without using a lot of memory if I use gcc-8

Comment: As a semi-educated guess without looking at the source, something related to inlining that isn't triggered by using `new` to construct the object?

Comment: First of all when you compile, make sure your -j options are set to just 1, having -j2,  -j3 calls 2 or 3 etc threads respectively, which can in theory multiply your compilation memory footprint. The second thing is in C++ if there are templated arguments, then the compiler needs to hardcode each data type for each type. If there are combinations of templates, the memory used goes up exponentially. There are ways to prevent the source code from overloading to some particular types, this can dramatically reduce your memory footprint during compilation.

Comment: I suspect that your use of a variadic initialiser, is somehow triggering some internal templating behaviour. Note that this doesn't compile on my gcc.

Comment: @Owl It is only `std::bitset<100....0> bs;`, nothing else;                                                                                                               -j1 is unrecognized command line option.

Comment: make -j1 i mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a known bug in GCC, having to do with `constexpr` initialisation of very large objects.

There are several bug reports, one of which is [bug 56671](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56671), reported in March, 2013 against v4.7.2. The bug was marked resolved in June, 2018, which means that it was present through to v7.3, at least, but has now been corrected.

If you need a workaround, it appears that using a different constructor did not trigger the bug. In particular, changing `std::bitset<size> bs;` to `std::bitset<size> bs(0);` compiles fine on various versions of gcc, including v.7.3.0 (according to the online compiler I tried).